# Use the definition of the derivative to differentiate $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, $x \not=0$. Without using the chain rule, find $f'(x)$. This is an easy problem using the chain rule, however, I am curious to see how one might do it with the definition of the derivative:
$$
\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\frac{e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-1/c^2}}{x-c},
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/(x+h)^2}-e^{-1/x^2}}{h}.
$$

Comment: "This is a type of function that isn't particularly easy to manipulate" -- Bear in mind this is quite true for MANY functions. It's part of why we develop rules like the product rule, quotient rule, chain rule, and more. It's because it allows us to handle certain combinations of functions outright, without having to appeal to the (often much) more difficult definitions.

Comment: Most certainly. I was just curious about this problem because I couldn't really find anything online about it, and the "definition of derivative calculators" couldn't solve it.

Comment: How exactly are you defining $e^x$? Because there would be a different solution if you are defining $e^x$ as "the function that when differentiated equals itself", compared to defining $e^x$ as the Maclaurin series, compared to defining $e^x$ as the limit of $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$.

Comment: Defining $e^x$ as the function when differentiated equals itself.

Comment: I imagine you can get the derivative you want by just mirroring the proof of the general chain rule. That is,$$(f(g(x))'=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}h = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)} \times \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h=\cdots$$with the appropriate choices of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} e^{-\frac1{x^2}} &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-\frac1{(x+h)^2}} - e^{-\frac1{x^2}}}{h} \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-\frac1{(x+h)^2}} - e^{-\frac1{x^2}}}{-\frac1{(x+h)^2} - \left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)} \times \lim_{h\to0} \frac{-\frac1{(x+h)^2} - \left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)}{h} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac2{x^3} \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-\frac1{(x+h)^2}} - e^{-\frac1{x^2}}}{\frac1{(x+h)^2} - \frac1{x^2}} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac2{x^3} \lim_{H\to0} \frac{e^{-H-\frac1{x^2}} - e^{-\frac1{x^2}}}{H} & H=\frac1{(x+h)^2}-\frac1{x^2} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac2{x^3} e^{-\frac1{x^2}} \lim_{H\to0} \frac{e^{-H} - 1}{H} \\[1ex]
&= \boxed{\frac2{x^3} e^{-\frac1{x^2}}} \lim_{\eta\to0} \frac{e^\eta-1}\eta & \eta=-H
\end{align*}$$

The remaining limit is $1$ as it's the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: How did you go from the 2nd to 3rd line?

Comment: The second limit in the second line is derivative of the "inner" function, i.e. $g(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$. I skipped a step to focus on the more complicated part.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the derivative, $\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}$, is only valid for $x\neq 0$, since the function $e^{-1/x^2}$ is not even defined at $0$. However, if we define
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2} & x\neq0\\
0 & x= 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
then we can evaluate the derivative of $f$ at $0$ using the definition of the derivative by
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=0.
$$

Comment: I was looking more for an answer that used the definition to get $\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}$, not just the derivative at 0